# Fixed/sticky div content shifts to the left after sticking to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I want to stick a certain div to the top when scrolling below it. After some research I found this solution. Everything works fine except that the content of the div shifts a little bit to the left when scrolling over it

**javascript**

```
    function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

**CSS**

```
    #sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
#sticky.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<hr />
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">
<center>Unternehmen Leistungen Kunden Stärken</center>
<hr /></div>
```

```js
    function sticky_relocate() {
      var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
      var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
      if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
      } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
      }
    }

    $(function() {
      $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
      sticky_relocate();
    });
```

```css
#sticky {
  padding: 0.5ex;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.5ex;
}
#sticky.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr />
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">
  <center>Unternehmen Leistungen Kunden Stärken</center>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: what does your html look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to center the `div` to prevent that shift.  To center a `div` with a `position:fixed;`, you need to set `left` and `right` to 0.

**The CSS**

```
#sticky.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
      var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
      var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
      if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
      } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
      }
    }

    $(function() {
      $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
      sticky_relocate();
    });
```

```css
#sticky {
  position:relative;
  padding: 0.5ex;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align:center;
}
#sticky.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.content {
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr />
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">
  Unternehmen Leistungen Kunden Stärken
  <hr />
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```